# GMT to Local Time Conversion with Daylight Saving Time change

Tags: ios, nsdate, nsdateformatter, nstimezone

From server I'm receiving GMT time structure(user defined structure), using that I want to convert it into local time, I have done it by filling the NSDatecomponent with the structure received, and then I have used date formattter to get date from it, everything works fine except one case. If the GMT time is after Nov 3 ([Daylight Saving Time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daylight_saving_time) change in US) formatter is producing 1 hour time difference.

for eg: If the intended time is for Nov-3 ,4 PM, after conversion from GMT to local its giving Nov-3, 3 PM.

Any idea how to avoid it.

**Edit:**

```
   // Selected Dates
   NSDateComponents *sel_date = [[NSDateComponents alloc]init];
    sel_date.second = sch_detail.sel_dates.seconds;
    sel_date.minute = sch_detail.sel_dates.mins;

    sel_date.hour   = sch_detail.sel_dates.hours;
    sel_date.day    = sch_detail.sel_dates.date;
    sel_date.month  = sch_detail.sel_dates.month;
    sel_date.year   = sch_detail.sel_dates.year;
    sel_date.timeZone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"GMT"];



    // Get the Date format.
    NSCalendar *gregorian = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
    [gregorian setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"GMT"]];

    // Start_date formatter.
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"MMM dd, yyyy hh:mm a"];
   [dateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone localTimeZone]];

   NSDate *strt_date_loc = [gregorian dateFromComponents:sel_date];


   // Get date string.
   NSString *sel_date_time = [dateFormatter stringFromDate: strt_date_loc];+
```

sel_date_time string is one hour less than what it supposed to be..

**Log :**

strt_date_loc = 2013-11-30 06:56:00 +0000

sel_date_time = Nov 29, 2013 10:56 PM (but it should be 11:56 PM)

TimeZone : Palo Alto (US)

**Local to gmt Conversion:**

```
- (NSDateComponents*) convert_to_gmt_time : (NSDate*) date
{
    NSDate *localDate = date;
    NSTimeInterval timeZoneOffset = [[NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone] secondsFromGMT];
    NSTimeInterval gmtTimeInterval = [localDate timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate] - timeZoneOffset;
    NSDate *gmtDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceReferenceDate:gmtTimeInterval];

    NSDateComponents *date_comp = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] components: NSDayCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSYearCalendarUnit | NSHourCalendarUnit | NSMinuteCalendarUnit | NSSecondCalendarUnit fromDate:gmtDate];

    return date_comp;
}
```

thanx.

Comment: Show your relevant code and show some sample data. Include actual log output of relevant values.

Comment: Sure give me a minute

Comment: Log `strt_date_loc` and `sel_date_time`. Paste the actual log output. And what timezone are you in?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your result is correct. The date formatter does not use the *current* time difference
between your local time and GMT, but the time difference that is in effect at the
date that is converted.

The daylight savings time is not in effect at that date,
so the difference between UTC/GMT and California time is 8 hours. 
Therefore

```
2013-11-30 06:56:00 +0000 = 2013-11-29 22:56:00 -0800 = Nov 29, 2013 10:56 PM
```

and that is what you got.

**ADDED:** Your conversion of the local date to GMT components does not work correctly
because

```
[[NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone] secondsFromGMT]
```

is the *current* time difference to GMT, and not the time difference that is in effect
at the date to be converted. 
The following should work correctly (as is even slightly shorter):

```
NSCalendar *cal = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
[cal setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT:0]];
NSDateComponents *date_comp = [cal components: NSDayCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSYearCalendarUnit | NSHourCalendarUnit | NSMinuteCalendarUnit | NSSecondCalendarUnit fromDate:localDate];
```

Comment: To explain a bit more… Normally the US west coast is 8 hours behind UTC (GMT) time. During Daylight Saving Time (DST), the US west coast is 7 hours behind UTC (GMT). See [Time changes in year 2013 for USA - California - Los Angeles](http://www.timeanddate.com/worldclock/clockchange.html?n=137). This year, 2013, DST began March 10 and ends November 3, Sunday, at 02:00.

Comment: Thanks for your answer and I got the problem, but how to handle this case, for eg: I'm scheduling a call at 4PM on Nov 4, which I converted to gmt and send to server, when I download back and do the gmt to local conversion, time shown as 3 PM, so do I need to check any condition while scheduling itself? I want the call to be established at 4 PM not 3 PM.

Comment: @fztest: That looks as if your conversion of "4PM on Nov 4" to GMT is wrong.

Comment: @MartinR Can you please check my edit. Is it OK. It works for normal cases, except the day light changes.