# Time zone conversion of date in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I get the time from webservice in this format : **2014-07-26 21:00:00** with timezone-offset : **GMT+0100**. I need to convert this for both **GMT** zone and local time zone.

For Eg:

Original Date : **2014-07-26 21:00:00**

to convert

GMT : **2014-07-26 20:00:00**

My time zone in india means i need to get **2014-07-27 01:30:00**

I tried lot of ways but I cant find any solution.. Pls Help me to fix this..

Comment: this might help u  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19675405/gmt-to-local-time-conversion-with-daylight-saving-time-change

Comment: use CFTimeZone https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreFoundation/Reference/CFTimeZoneRef/Reference/reference.html

Comment: I have timezone-offset can you pls give some code to understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you have to convert the input date string to `NSDate`.
This is done with a `NSDateFormatter` where the date format matches the input string.
In your case you would set the time zone explicitly:

```
NSString *origDateString = @"2014-07-26 21:00:00";

NSDateFormatter *fmt = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[fmt setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];
[fmt setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"GMT+0100"]];
NSDate *date = [fmt dateFromString:origDateString];
```

Now you can convert the `NSDate` back to a string according to different time 
zones:

```
[fmt setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT:0]];
NSString *gmtDateString = [fmt stringFromDate:date];
NSLog(@"%@", gmtDateString);
// 2014-07-26 20:00:00

[fmt setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone localTimeZone]];
NSString *localDateString = [fmt stringFromDate:date];
NSLog(@"%@", localDateString);
// 2014-07-26 22:00:00 (my GMT offset is +02:00)
```

Comment: Thanks Wait I ll check this..